# Why do so many functions used in data science have derivatives of the form f(x)*(1-f(x))?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, activation-function

The sigmoid function's derivative is of that form, and so is the softmax function's. Is this by design, or some strange coincidence that seems to work for ML models/neural networks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sigmoid function is a [partial case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier) of softmax, when the number of classes $K=2$. That's why the similarity of their derivatives shouldn't surprise you.

> Why do so many functions used in data science have derivatives of the
>   form f(x)*(1-f(x))?

If you consider the following differential equation

$y' = y \cdot (1-y)$

you will find the general solution in the form

$y(x) = \frac{e^x}{c + e^x} = \frac{1}{1 + c e^{-x}}$

So, in some sense, there are not that many functions with this property: they are "very like" sigmoid function.